# How to paste values from one sheet to another to last row of specific column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A novice on app scripts, but managed to successfully build my own script through much research, but now my script is running into errors. Below is my current code:

```
  function MyFunction() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Daily Sales'); 
  var range = ss.getRange('B8:H83'); 
  var data = range.getValues();
  var OUrange = ss.getRange('K8:Q83'); 
  var OUdata = OUrange.getValues();  
  var ts = sss.getSheetByName('Tracker'); 


  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); 
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,OUdata.length, OUdata[0].length).setValues(OUdata);

}
```

In the Daily Sales sheet I am copying values from columns B-H and K-Q and pasting them in the last row of the Tracker sheet starting at Column A. The Daily Sales values in Col. K-Q are pasted correctly below the B-H values, so happy with those results.

On the Tracker sheet these values are in Columns A-G. However I have since added formulas in Columns I and J based on the script data and a manual entry in Column H. These formulas are copied down the entire column within the sheet (i.e. row 5000). Since adding these formulas, the script is now pasting values in A5001.

I realize it is because of these formulas, but is there a way to update my script to paste in the last row of column A while maintaining those formulas in Columns I and J? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper function that computes the first free row of a given column (NOT a column with formulas)

```
function MyFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Daily Sales'); 
var range = ss.getRange('B8:H83'); 
var data = range.getValues();
var OUrange = ss.getRange('K8:Q83'); 
var OUdata = OUrange.getValues();  
var ts = sss.getSheetByName('Tracker'); 
var values = data.concat(OUdata).filter(function (r) {return r[0]});
var fr = findFirstFreeRow(ts, 1) // second parameter represents column to check for first free row
ts.getRange(fr, 1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); 
}


function findFirstFreeRow(sheet, colNum) {
var v = sheet.getRange(1, colNum, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(),
    l = v.length,
    r;
while (l >= 0) {
    if (v[l] && v[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
        r = (l + 2);
        break;
        } else {
        l--;
        }
    }
return r;
}
```

See if that helps?

Comment: As a helper function, is this a separate script that I will need to run? I used the above code and receiving errors for undefined fr and undefined sheet on the findFirstFreeRow function.

Comment: No, you only run the first function. The second is called from the first function when needed. If you need further help, please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks, here is a shared link to a sample version of my [spreadsheet]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nt396R_Sf64kdx2_inmzBFXqGealmYSARzRlNfildNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the code change while (l > 0) to while (l >= 0). I already updated this line in my answer. See if that works?

Comment: This fixed it and code is running correctly with one exception. It is only pasting the 'OUdata' from K8:Q83 and not the 'data' from B8:H83. When I remove the 2nd ts.getRange code it pastes the B8:H83 data, but obviously not the 'OUdata'.

Comment: Hi, correct. The second setValues overwrites the first. I did not check the complete code at first. I changed your first function a bit (posted above). See if it now works as intended?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the extra empty rows from your 'Tracker' sheet, you can use the [`appendRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) function to create a new row with the manual values (leaving the cells that need formulas blank).

After the manual values are in, you can then get the cells that need formulas and use [`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setformulaformula) on them.

For the sake of brevity, if you wanted column A,B,C,E,F to have manual values and column D to have a formula you would do:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow(['A','B','C','','E','F']);
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setFormula('=FORMULA(HERE)');
```